# Java check two date as String

Tags: java, string

simply i have two variable as date which they are date as String, for example

"2016-11-30"

when i try to check two variable as this value i get false,

```
// serverDateTime value is:           "2016-11-30"
// Utils.getCurrentDateTime() return: "2016-11-30"

private boolean checkCurrentDate(String serverDateTime) {
    if (serverDateTime.equals(Utils.getCurrentDateTime())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static String getCurrentDateTime() {
    Calendar         c  = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return df.format(c.getTime());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Print the values of both date strings.

Comment: Note that your method can be simplified to `return serverDateTime.equals(Utils.getCurrentDateTime());` - no need for an `if` statement. It won't change the result, but... you can also just use `new Date()` in the `format` code - there's no need to create a `Calendar`.

Comment: Also, `String#equals()` already returns the `boolean` value you want.  The whole if/else is superfluous and could be reduced to `return serverDateTime.equals(Utils.getCurrentDateTime());`

Comment: I can't reproduce

Comment: Seems good to me ... code is correct (not perfect but good logic). Execution works too.

Comment: @AxelH I'm wondering when i debugging code i get `false`, when i print result i get `true`

Comment: This looks like a bad usage of IntelliJ Debugger or a bug, the last would be unlikely but why not, using Calendar in debug mode.

Comment: Check the length of the two string. Might have non printable character.

Comment: @ortis Thanks, its very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use moment.js

```
var stringDateOne = '2016-11-30';
var stringDateTwo = '2016-11-30';
var momentDateOne = moment(stringDateOne, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
var momentDateTwo = moment(stringDateTwo, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

if(momentDateOne.diff(momentDateTwo, 'days') == 0){
   //date equal
}else{
   //date not equal
}
```

Comment: He is in Java, no in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

hi The code is correct and is returning true for the above entries

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currDate = "2016-11-30";
    HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
    System.out.println(hw.checkCurrentDate(currDate));
}
private boolean checkCurrentDate(String serverDateTime) {
    if (serverDateTime.equals(HelloWorld.getCurrentDateTime())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
public static String getCurrentDateTime() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return df.format(c.getTime());
}
```

}